# Table not fitting to 100% height

Tags: javascript, html, css

Edit: Updated with code in answer

I have a table that I need to fill 100% height and keep the width the same as the height. I'm using `vh` to try and accomplish this.

index.html:

```js
var board = document.getElementById('board');
var draw = '';
var letters = 'abcdefgh';
var init = '♖♘♗♕♔♗♘♖♙♙♙♙♙♙♙♙                                ♟♟♟♟♟♟♟♟♜♞♝♛♚♝♞♜';
for (var column = 8; column > 0; column--) {
  draw += '<tr id="' + column + '" class="row">';
  for (var row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
    draw += '<td id="' + letters.charAt(row) + column + '" class="tile">' + init.charAt(row + 8 * column - 8) + '</td>';
  }
  draw += '</tr>';
}
board.innerHTML = draw;
```

```css
html,
body, td, th {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#board-wrapper,
#board {
  border-spacing: 0;
  float: left;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
}
.tile {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 6vh;
  height: 12.5vh;
  width: 12.5vh;
  text-align: center;
}
.row:nth-child(even) .tile:nth-child(odd),
.row:nth-child(odd) .tile:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #777;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <title>TitaniumChess</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <table id="board-wrapper">
    <tbody id="board"></tbody>
  </table>
  <script src="main.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

However, this takes up more that 100% height. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

You need to reset the browsers default `td padding` value. I'd recommend that you use a CSS reset, like [normalize.css (link to HTML5Boilerplate)](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/css/normalize.css) which does that for you:

```
/* Tables


/**
 * Remove most spacing between table cells.
 */

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a spot on answer, but it might also be useful to add in that the reason that this is the answer because the [height is calculated inside the padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height). And the orginal code was setting each table cell to the 1/8 of the height of the window, and then the padding was being added.

Comment: This makes the table too small now. I've updated the live example so you can see the problem.

Comment: @Hopeless the padding is added from the start because the `td` element inherits the default browser padding value. If the OP doesn't want to reset it, he can then use `box-sizing: border-box` property, which will include the padding value to the height.

Comment: @JulianLachniet well, it's "small" now because the code snippets iframe windows is small, and you're using the`vh` value.

Comment: @Vucko Take a look at http://app.lachniet.com/ now. Even when its not in an iframe (embeded here), it's too small.

Comment: No, it has white space at the bottom